# TLS clientAuth requires ExtKeyUsageClientAuth through whole certificate chain

Tags: authentication, ssl, go, x509

I'm trying out TLS client authentication using go. It worked fine when I created a simple self-signed client certificate with ExtKeyUsageClientAuth set, but when a client tries to connect with a longer certificate chain:

CA -> intermediate -> client

I get the following error: `x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage`

The relevant calls are

[handshake_server.go:](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/tls/handshake_server.go) `processCertsFromClient()`

[verify.go:](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/x509/verify.go) `checkChainForKeyUsage()`

and if I'm reading the code right it looks like every single certificate in my chain must have the client auth extended key set.

I'm no x509 expert but that seems like a strange requirement, I've never seen a CA or an intermediate certificate that had client auth set. I don’t see how can you be expected to configure a long lived CA to handle all possible future key usages.

So where's the mistake?

I can think of a few possibilities

1. I don’t understand TLS (likely)
2. my assumption that client auth works much like server auth is wrong
3. I’m reading the code wrong
4. my tls server is misconfigured
5. golang's TLS client auth implementation is wrong

Comment: I looked into this a bit, since I wrote some of that code. I initially thought you were mistaken, but started to agree with you after reading verify.go. I think you are actually in the best position of all to answer this. Use your existing test case and add a bunch of println in verify.go, and you'll be able to convince yourself this is a bug that you need to file.

Comment: I've hit this problem too and have submitted a bug report: [issue 7423](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=7423)

Comment: The discussion on http://golang.org/issue/7423 suggests that this is working as intended. The comments there explain how to generate correct certificates.